# repeat elements in vector 1 with the elemnts in vector 2

Tags: r

I got two vectors.

```
tst <- c("www","ddd","ggg","hhh")
ks <- c(2,3,4,0)
```

I want to repeat elements in tst ks times. How can I get the following result as a list or a vector.

```
www, www, ddd, ddd, ddd, ggg, ggg, ggg, ggg, hhh
```

If zero in ks, still I want the element to be present. I assume this is simple. But cannot figure it out. I have a large data frame (>1,000,000). A code using base R is preferred.

Thanks

Comment: So would ks=0 really mean ks=1?

Comment: Yes, ks=0 really means ks=1. But i do not want to change it. I tried if(ks>0) rep(tst,ks) else tst, but there is an error.

Comment: `rep(tst, pmax(ks, 1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmax` to ensure there is atleast one instance of `tst` present in the vector.

```
rep(tst, pmax(ks, 1))
#[1] "www" "www" "ddd" "ddd" "ddd" "ggg" "ggg" "ggg" "ggg" "hhh"
```

Comment: Thanks, what pmax does here?

Comment: `pmax` selects whichever is maximum between `ks` or 1. See this another example : `pmax(c(-1, -2, 4, 5, 6), 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Given this constraint

> If zero in ks, still I want the element to be present.

Maybe a dummy ks variable will help?

```
tst <- c("www","ddd","ggg","hhh")
ks <- c(2,3,4,0)
ks2<-ks
ks2[ks2 == 0] <- 1

rep(tst, ks2)
```

> [1] "www" "www" "ddd" "ddd" "ddd" "ggg" "ggg" "ggg" "ggg" "hhh"

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to replace 0 elements in ks with 1.